# No unused expressions on function inside componentDidMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

How can I fix or disable ESLint to ignore

```
[eslint] Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression. (no-unused-expressions)
```

on this

```
authUser
  ? this.setState(() => ({ authUser }))
  : this.setState(() => ({ authUser: null }));
```

Whilst, I understand the reason for the error and could just ignore it - as it's doing everything that it's is intended for.

Is there a way to remove this error from this document only, not globally? Or perhaps, is there a better way for me to rewrite this to avoid the error whilst achieving the same outcome?

**Full Component**

```
const withAuthentication = Component =>
  class WithAuthentication extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
        authUser: null
      };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      firebase.auth.onAuthStateChanged(authUser => {
        authUser
          ? this.setState(() => ({ authUser }))
          : this.setState(() => ({ authUser: null }));
      });
    }

    render() {
      const { authUser } = this.state;

      return (
        <AuthUserContext.Provider value={authUser}>
          <Component {...this.props} />
        </AuthUserContext.Provider>
      );
    }
  };

export default withAuthentication;
```

Comment: Would you still get the warning if you just do `this.setState({authUser})` without using a callback?

Comment: Same thing @SungKim. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about trying if then else?

```
firebase.auth.onAuthStateChanged(authUser => {
  if (authUser)
    this.setState(() => ({ authUser })) 
  else
    this.setState(() => ({ authUser: null })); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks. That is the method I ended up taking.